# I need to remove every repetitive character from string that given as array

Tags: javascript

I need to remove every repetitive character from string, all should be good, its working for strings that already given as 'string', but if i get array and then transform it to string it didnt work.

```js
function minValue(values){
  values = values.toString("").split(",").join("");
    let result = values.replace(/(.)\1+/g, '$1');
     return result;
}
console.log(minValue([4, 7, 5, 7]));
```

Comment: what result do you expect?

Comment: The example you show gives the output "4757". Since that has no repeated characters in, it seems to be working just fine. You'll need to provide some more explanation of what you expected to happen, and why you think this "didn't work".

Comment: `values.toString("").split(",").join("")` - that's the same as just `values.join("")` here.

Comment: You need to provide examples

Comment: `.replace(/(.)\1+/g, '$1')` works only when the consecutive characters are duplicate. There are no consective duplicate in the array. If you pass `[4, 7, 5, 5]`, it returns `475`

Comment: @NinaScholz i expext 475

Comment: Seems like maybe you want `[...new Set(values)].join('')`, but if the input is `[1, 2, 12]` then that would become `1212`. Is that what you want? Or do you want to concatenate and then remove all duplicate characters? That would be ``[...new Set(values.join(''))].join('')``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is not clear enough, if the Value will be a string or an Array, i've added a guarding if statement, that converts possible strings to an array.

```js
function minValue(values){
  // If you get a string, you'll need to split this into an array
  if(typeof values === "string") values = values.split("");
  
  // A set only accepts distinct values and we can create a new 
  // set by providing an array as a base.
  // We then create a new Array by using the Array.from() mothod, 
  // which can use an array-like structure, to create a new array.
  // This way, we remove any duplicate value from an array and 
  // return the result as a string, by joining all items together.
  return Array.from(new Set(values)).join("");
}

console.log(minValue([4, 7, 5, 7]));
```